# NordVpn Cli Blacklist?

Tags: javascript, udp, vpn, vps, openvpn

I am hosting a website on a digital ocean VPS. For part of the functionality of the website I need to be connected to a VPN connection, I have a NordVpn connection and am using the CLI in Linux. Once connected to the VPN traffic to my website is blocked. is there any way of turning off the nordvpn whitelist or just having outgoing requests go threw it? I am using OpenVPN technology and UDP protocol.

I have tried whitelisting x.x.x.x/x for a subnet (invalid subnet error) and googling the issue in all imaginable working I can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to whitelist all subnets...
can be done with the commands

```
nordvpn whitelist add subnet 128.0.0.0/1
nordvpn whitelist add subnet 0.0.0.0/1
```

This adds all IP address to the whitelist and makes the website visable from the whole internet

Answer (score 0):

First, something to consider:

- Are you allowing incoming traffic from all relevant sources and HTTP(S) ports in your digitalocean hosted website, or only from specific IP ranges?

If not, traffic would be broken to the website, due to restrictive firewall rules in: https://cloud.digitalocean.com/networking/firewalls

If you want to add your digitalocean host to openvpn exclusions, you can do this by adding this line to the client config file:

```
route add <digitalocean-host-IP> mask 255.255.255.255 default_gateway_ip
```

Make sure to use the netmask notation as is, and not a slash notation `1.1.1.1/32`

You can find the default_gateway_ip like this:

- Diconnect from the nordvpn.

Then issue:

```
ip r | grep default
```

This should give you the router's default_gateway:

For me it is:

`default via 192.168.178.1 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp metric 100`

Re-run openvpn with the amended config file:

`openvpn --config path/to/file.ovpn`

Comment: Thanks, I have no firewalls active on my VPS. I am not using OpenVPN directly but rather connect using the nordvpn cli.

Comment: @mooncraftman which OS? Linux, Windows, Android? One thing to consider: split tunneling is not available on Linux, yet. 
To whitelist the remote ip from nordvpn cli, you can type this: `nordvpn whitelist add subnet 172.16.0.0/32` - replace 172.6.0.0 with the public ip of your vps web server.

Comment: Im using ubuntu lunix 22.10

Comment: @mooncraftman, please check the above comment and let me know if you tried  `nordvpn whitelist add subnet 172.16.0.0/32` - replace 172.6.0.0 with the public ip of your vps web server. This is working for my webserver that I created to test your scenario.

Comment: I have, it was not the solution